# Testing IE10 on win7

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, internet-explorer-10

I have Windows 7, and I want to check how my website works on IE 10. Unfortunatly, I can't setup Win 8 to virtual box.

Comment: I don't think you can, why cant you use virtual box?

Comment: Download IE 10 Preview http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Info/Downloads/Default.html

Comment: You can get "IE10 - Win8" image for virtualbox here http://www.modern.ie/en-US/virtualization-tools

Answer (score 13):

You need Windows 8 to use IE10 currently ([Microsoft's website](https://connect.microsoft.com/ie)).

Luckily you can get Windows 8 preview [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/consumer-preview) and install it with virtual box, but be sure to grab the `iso` ([tutorial](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-install-windows-8-on-virtualbox/)).

**Update:**

IE10 is now [available](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/downloads/ie-10/worldwide-languages) for Windows 7.
IE11 is [available](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie-11-worldwide-languages) as well.

Answer (score 5):

Internet Explorer 10 is not supported by Windows 7 for this Beta.

You will have to wait more time to get it on Windows 7 (if Microsoft wants to release it on Windows 7) or try to install Windows 8 Consumer Preview ([Get it here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/consumer-preview)) on your Virtual Box or on a special hard disk to try your website.

You can find a good tutorial about installing Windows 8 with VirtualBox here :
[VirtualBox Install - Windows 8 Consumer Preview](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2241-virtualbox-install-windows-8-consumer-preview.html)

Another good way is to use BrowserStack which let you try IE10 from this website for 30 minutes (free version), you can find it there : [BrowserStack - Online Browser](http://www.browserstack.com/) but you may have some bugs with the Internet Explorer 10 option.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't be supported in release as well, just as IE9 is not available on WinXP.

Comment: I heard some months ago that they will release it on Windows 7 but maybe they changed their mind (post edited to be sure)

Comment: Wiki gives nothing in support of that.

Comment: Yes we will see their choice you are probably right about that ;)

Comment: IE10 **will be released to Windows 7** according to the [IE10 Developer Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673549(v=vs.85).aspx): "*When it's released, Internet Explorer 10 will be available for Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2, and Windows Server 2012.*"

Comment: ie10 is now available in windows 7 as an optional update in windows update.

Answer (score 3):

Check any online renderer, as

http://netrenderer.com/

It served me well, and you can also define the starting position where to start the actual output. IE version is definable as well, and 10 Consumer Preview is here too.

I develop web stuff on GNU/Linux, and IE is not an option for me in testing. But I only need visual preview, so this made it easier many many times before :-)

Comment: A renderer is **insufficient** (and IE10CP (PP5) < IE10RP (PP6)). If I want to use an online service, I'd use http://browserstack.com/. I'm not using it, because of the significant delay. Just like you, I also develop on Linux., but I'm using a single VM for cross-browser testing. I've posted a Q&A (see my profile) in which I guide how to set up a XP VM (soon to be Win7). I have successfully isolated a IE9 package from Win 7, which works in an environment where IE9 has never been installed. In the future, IE10 will run on Win7, but I'd rather a working solution *now*.

Answer (score 3):

You can setup Virtual Box for Windows 8 following this tutorial.
[Tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Windows-8-in-VirtualBox)

<strike>Although IE 10 will be available for Windows 7 only after general availability for Windows 8 is announced i.e late October 2012. But you can currently install the preview of IE 10 on your Win7 machine and test your webpage You can download it [here](http://internet-explorer-10-platform-preview.en.softonic.com/)</strike>

**Update**
IE 10 is now available for Windows 7. You can download it [here](http://internet-explorer-10.en.softonic.com/).

Comment: As I said in the bounty notice and the other comments: I DO already have SEVERAL Win8+IE10 combinations. IE10 PP2 is barely useful for testing web pages against IE10 compliance, because it's very outdated. I'd be glad to see a method to run IE10 PP6 in Win7 or WinPE.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet for now is to install Windows 8 and use it on there.  However, if you're stuck to Windows 7 for some reason, Microsoft have announced [IE10 will support Windows 7 at release](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> When it's released, Internet Explorer 10 will be available for Windows
>   7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2, and Windows Server 2012.

So you could just wait it out and get the final release on Windows 7 in a few months.

Alternatively, IE10 Platform Preview 2 apparently works on Windows 7:

> The most recent release for Windows 7 was Internet Explorer 10
>   Platform Preview Build 2, on June 29, 2011.

IE10 PP2 is old tech and might not be the best thing for testing on, since the real IE10 is probably different.  Still, it may be better than nothing.

Comment: I do know that IE10 is going to be released for Win 7 near the end of the year. I also have a Win 8 VM at the moment. I want to get a working IE10 render engine in Win 7, so that I can throw away the Win8 VM, which is unstable and frequently hogs CPU and SSD space. IE10PP2 is a no-go, it's extremely outdated, and doesn't reflect a real situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the online tools like  http://netrenderer.com/ or http://browsershots.org/ to get the browser shots of your site.

Also, there is a great tool to test sites in IE 5.5 - 10, it's called IETester. You can download it from http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: http://browsershots.org/ seems to be a payment-only site. Did I do something wrong or won't it show any screenshots w/o payment?

Comment: browsershots.org you may use freely but you have to wait and unfortunately sometimes a lot.

Answer (score 1):

How about vmware player? It's also free.

And here is the instruction how to deploy Windows 8 on it: http://ludwigkeck.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/windows-8-on-vmware-player/

And another one just in case: http://dreevoo.com/en/content.php?id=587

Comment: As I mentioned in the bounty notice, I do have already some Win 8 VMs. I'm looking for a method to get IE10 running in Win 7 (either through an unsupported/undocumented method/hack, through [VMware ThinApp](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/overview.html), or another application virtualisation/sandboxing method. A method to get IE10 fully working in [Windows PE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_pe) is also OK, because Windows PE is a very lightweight Windows version. I can already start and use IE10 in Windows PE 4, but the lack of DirectX 11 support causes several web pages to crash.